# Looking for a nice linux program debugger

Tags: linux, debugging

I have been compiling my programs using GCC via the terminal, and im looking for a debugger with more detail

thanks

Comment: Define "more detail".  Also, it depends a lot on the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried gdb?

Answer (score 5):

Here's some other popular discussions of this question:

[Best C++ Debugger For Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217880/best-c-debugger-for-linux)

[Linux C++ Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436400/linux-c-debugger)

[Which is the best Linux C/C++ debugger (or front-end to gdb) to help teaching programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79537/which-is-the-best-linux-c-c-debugger-or-front-end-to-gdb-to-help-teaching-pro)

[What is a good unix alternative to DDD (Data Display Debugger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206544/what-is-a-good-unix-alternative-to-ddd-data-display-debugger)

You can find more by putting "linux debugger" in the search box in the upper right.

Comment: This is best answer to the question 9and DDD might probably be the best GDB front-end)

Answer (score 3):

gdb is pretty much *the debugger* on linux. Other things you will meet are all, or nearly all, wrappers on gdb (emacs, eclipse, various other guis).

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend `cgdb`. It's like gdb's TUI but much better, with syntax highlighting of the code.

Really useful to see the code while you debug, but not getting into a graphical debugger either.

Comment: I've not seen many people use it but I absolutely love it. It nicely complements my preference for vim and command line tools.

Answer (score 1):

[gdb](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) is the console debugger. 
if work with console base debugger hard for you , you can use Data Display Debugger ([DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/)) that base on gdb or [KGDB](http://kgdb.linsyssoft.com/) that use in KDE environment.

other solution is used IDE like Netbeans , Eclipse , Anjuta , Kdevelop , ... also core for  debugging is gdb .

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at insight and ddd, both wrappers around gdb. You could also use Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

why don't  use an IDE like [CodeLite](http://www.codelite.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The KDE IDE [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) has an experience similar to Visual Studio if that's what you're looking for. Don't let the name fool you, it's a general-purpose IDE - not just limited to Qt/KDE programs.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Zero bugs](http://www.zero-bugs.com/2.0/product_intro.html) a few times.  It seemed pretty powerful.  However I usually end up using gdb cli or curses as thats what I know best.

Answer (score 0):

I used gdb, gdbtui and Nemiver. They are all not as good as Visual C++, which is the Gold Standard of C++ Debugging, but of course only available for Windows.
There are are also KDevelop and Slickedit's debugging function. The latter did not work for me out of the box.