# stack trace analysis tools

Tags: c++, crash, stack-trace

are there any recommendations for tools that can analyze the stack trace from a crash? If not, are there any guides to writing one? I mean a tool that can look at a bunch of these dumps and catch patterns. These are crash logs of c++ applications.

Comment: which platform/compiler?

Comment: Linux. However, I fear I've mist-stated my question. I want a tool that I can use to spot patterns among stack traces. I will close this and re-state the question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows I recommend WinDbg: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009 there are various useful sites you can google for that will describe how to use it.

You can also open crash dumps using Visual Studio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk551230%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

There is a similar SO post here for linux: [Which is the best Linux C/C++ debugger (or front-end to gdb) to help teaching programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79537/which-is-the-best-linux-c-c-debugger-or-front-end-to-gdb-to-help-teaching-pr)

gdb should be fine for what you are asking for and Eclipse